# Как прочитать все сообщения в беседе ВК с помощью бота?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

**Описание**: имеется беседа в ВК с 3+ собеседниками, туда добавлен бот от моей группы; боту выданы все права, выбрана самая актуальная версия longpool.

**Задача**: необходимо получить все сообщения, которые были ранее написаны в беседе. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать? Буду рад любой помощи!

**Попробовано**: уже получилось запросить информацию о беседе с помощью запроса `method('messages.getConversationsById', {'peer_ids': 2000000000 + id, 'unread': 0, 'filter': 'all', 'extended': 1})`, но данный запрос не выводит информации о СООБЩЕНИЯХ пользователей.

Был опробован запрос `messages.getHistory`, но он не работает по причине того, что запрос происходит в многопользовательской беседе, а не в личных сообщениях группы.

Еще был опробован запрос `messages.getDialogs`, но, как говорится в официальной документации ВК, что он устарел и лучше его не использовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у ботов-сообществ история переписки в беседах не сохраняется, поэтому у всех сообщений id = 0 и метод вызвать не получится. Можно попробовать user-token, но для его получения требуется обращение в тех. поддержку ВК.

**UPDATE**. Произвести сбор всех сообщений можно с помощью метода "getMessageById"